# Reporting leaked passwords in github repository

Tags: git, disclosure

I have just found a handful of repositories on github that contain database passwords. I want to let the concerned parties know about this so that they can change their passwords and remove the password from the git history.

All of these repos look to be web sites built by web agencies for their clients. All the repos are under the same account, each repo refers to different web agencies.

I'm not sure how I should proceed. I don't think that I should just open issues, because this would just put more light on the issues.

How should I proceed?

Comment: If they've have a contribution guide, you can always submit a pull request.

Comment: Sadly they don't. I don't think that they intended for people to contribute.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able view the email address associated with a commit to the repo in the `git log`, the easiest way to view this on github by adding `.patch` to the URL

for example:

https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d77b0405ce6b471cb5ce3a904368fc25e55643d

the patch URL is:

https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d77b0405ce6b471cb5ce3a904368fc25e55643d.patch

This will give you the commit data, from which you can get the author's email address - you should be able to contact them on that!